# Best practice for handling server side validation in modal forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have an html form that is displayed in a modal window and, when submitted, will be validated by my server. When the form is submitted:

- if it passes validation the modal will close and the parent screen will be updated
- if it fails validation the modal will be updated with a replacement html form which will include a validation error message

Currently my http responses are all in html format and have a response code of 200 so javascript is unable to distinguish what to do.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to let javascript know whether to display the response body in the modal or the parent.

- I could use http response codes or parameters in the response header;
- I could do responses in json with a flag for success or failure and a json object containing html text;
- I could do an http redirect on success;
- I could do a json response for success and html response for validation failure
- ... etc

So what's the most standard way for handling this situation?

Comment: It obviously depends on the project, but I'd say almost always go for JSON for AJAX. Personally, even if my AJAX returns a single value, I wrap it in JSON so that, if I ever need to return more than that vaule, I can do it without changing a lot of code.

Comment: For sure, you need to validate the data before saving them into database or doing appropriate business object operations, because you can't never rely on user-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this question will be downvoted as too opinionated, but here's my two cents. Don't use HTTP response codes unless you are *very* certain you know what you're doing and want this method. Use JSON every time, instead of HTML or HTML and JSON. It's much more flexible and extendable than returning HTML and doing a simple DOM update. As you mentioned, there's no good way to indicate an error or success condition when you're just returning HTML. Using JSON you can return an array of errors to be applied, add in a status flag, and any other features you may need. You can then write more Javascript to handle successes and errors.